# How to use basic4android exported apk

Tags: android, export, basic4android

I am a .net developer but new to android programming. I have used basic for android and set to compile & run project into my LG device. Everything is good but my question is when I compile and run, everything is done?

Can I use the exported application file in the project folder in any device? I wrote a app and send it to my other galaxy phone, it worked! But when starting app, it works but first showing message: "Waiting for IDEdebugger to connect", what is this?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you package your application in b4a for other users or uploading to store, you have to ***change the compilation mode from debug to release or release(obfuscated).***

If you compile in debug mode, that is when if you share the application to different users, it will always launch with the information waiting for ide debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The app will work upon the platform which you choosed when you started your project. See what platform you choosed I remember there are Android , android icecream sandwich ..etc
So upon your choice you can know what devices you app will work but take care about the screen dimensions variations because this may cause problems in the way of the design is displayed so you should create scale just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of that error you should uncheck Project->Attach Debugger. Also the file you will upload to Google Play Store or other places will be a .apk file in your objects subfolder. Basically you will need to either setup the Galaxy phone like your LG device or change the project to release and copy the .apk file onto your SD card and manually install it. For more information on your error a quick Google search led to a forum post on Basic 4 Android's forum. The link to that post is http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/waiting-for-ide-debugger-to-connect.13813/